# Div Click Event not firing

Tags: asp.net

I have a page where i have a div element as below,

```
  `<div id="Dailymain" runat="server" class=" sidebar" onclick="ClickDaily">
 <div runat="server" id="Daily" class="sidebar_item" onclick="ClickDaily" >
       <h2><a id="Daily" href="Productivity.aspx">Daily</a></h2>            
        <p>                                     </p>
      </div><!--close sidebar_item--> 
    </div>`
```

and in my page_load code i have this,

```
  Weekly.Attributes["onclick"] = this.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this,        "ClickWeekly");
```

and in IPost Back EventHandler Members interface i have this..

```
 'if (eventArgument == "ClickWeekly")    
 {
 Weekly_Click();
  }'
```

but when that div element is clicked the click event function is not firing..where am i missing here.please help me...

Comment: check on rendered html that click event is bind to that div or not  ?

Comment: hi Kuzgun..if its easier with Jquery can u pls post the code here..Im new to this ASP.NET development.hope u can help

Comment: hi rahularyan, how to  check that??

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add the click handler to an object called Weekly - but in the markup you posted there is no element with that id.

You also have multiple elements with the same id "Daily" - id attributes should be unique.

As mentioned above, the onclick() function calls javascript - you will need to define a javascript function which causes a postback and invokes the server side function you need.  Or could you implement the server side function as javascript instead?

Answer (score -1):

Write a code like this
Step 1: In Page Load event

```
    Dailymain.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return ClickDaily()")
```

Step 2: Define javascript event

```
 function ClickDaily()
 {
    alert("call daily");
    return false;
 }
```